# Make Folder Partially Accessible

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I want to make files in a bucket accessible to everyone I give a link to, but I don't want the users to be able to see ALL the files in a bucket.  How do I do that?

I've got the folders set up, but anyone who has a link to one of the files can figure out how to see all the files.

I have all users select with storage object viewer.  Everyone and anyone can see the files.

When I give a link to a client, I want him to be able to see that file only or all the files in his folder.  But I don't want him to see the links in the other folders of the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the access to the buckets and objects using Cloud Identity and Access Management (Cloud IAM) permissions.
Cloud IAM allows you to control who has access to your buckets and objects.

You can controll the access to individual objects, in your buckets, see Access Control Lists.

I add the next link:

https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/using-iam-permissions

Comment: But is it possible to allow anyone I give a link to see the file and then have them NOT be able to see the files in the bucket.  Right now, anyone can see the files, but they can go to the root of the folder or bucket and see everything.  I want to not allow them to see everything and I don't want to put allow access individually.